# Ошибка при разворачивании проекта Maven: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, wildfly

Пытаюсь развернуть проект в WildFly-10.0.0

```
Product summary:

     - IDE: Eclipse
     - Build: Maven
     - Framework: Vaadin
     - Server: WildFly 10.0.0
```

Получаю об ошибке развертывания.

```
    16:38:35,627 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."OR.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."OR.war".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "OR.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0161: Failed to get manifest for deployment "/D:/dev/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/OR.war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang3-3.6.jar"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestAttachmentProcessor.getManifest(ManifestAttachmentProcessor.java:78)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestAttachmentProcessor.deploy(ManifestAttachmentProcessor.java:65)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:122)
    at org.jboss.vfs.util.PaddedManifestStream.read(PaddedManifestStream.java:39)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:170)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.fill(Manifest.java:441)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.readLine(Manifest.java:375)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.readLine(Manifest.java:409)
    at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:376)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:199)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:69)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFSUtils.readManifest(VFSUtils.java:243)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFSUtils.getManifest(VFSUtils.java:227)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestAttachmentProcessor.getManifest(ManifestAttachmentProcessor.java:76)
    ... 7 more

16:38:35,637 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "OR.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"OR.war\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"OR.war\".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"OR.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0161: Failed to get manifest for deployment \"/D:/dev/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/OR.war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang3-3.6.jar\"
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)"}}
16:38:35,775 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "OR.war" (runtime-name : "OR.war")
16:38:35,780 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."OR.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."OR.war".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "OR.war"

16:38:36,457 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
16:38:36,457 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
16:38:36,457 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) started (with errors) in 10342ms - Started 269 of 556 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 371 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
16:38:36,497 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment OR.war (runtime-name: OR.war) in 4ms
16:38:36,587 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0009: Undeployed "OR.war" (runtime-name: "OR.war")
16:38:36,587 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."OR.war".STRUCTURE

16:38:41,341 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found OR.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called OR.war.dodeploy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка

> java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

говорит о поврежденном JAR-файле.

Не ясно, где находится битая библиотека и почему она попадает в сборку. Попробуйте выполнить чистую сборку и развернуть приложение заново:

1. Удалите приложение целиком из WildFly
2. Остановите WildFly.
3. Выполните чистую сборку (`mvn clean install`)
4. Распакуйте полученный WAR-файл.
5. Убедитесь, что проблемный JAR-файл (`lib\commons-lang3-3.6.jar`) совпадает с таким же файлом в центральном репозитории Maven (http://central.maven.org). Зависимости можно искать в репозитории по кординатам. В Вашем случае ссылка на файл: [commons-lang3-3.6.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.6/commons-lang3-3.6.jar)
6. Попробуйте установить приложение заново.

Если на пятом шаге выяснилось, что в сборку попадает неправильный файл, то, возможно, Вы установили зависимость вручную и она сохранена в локальном репозитории. Попробуйте:

- удалить библиотеку из локального репозитория (`~/.m2/repository`) удалите каталог соответствующий проблемной библиотеке (в данном случае: `org\apache\commons\commons-lang3`;
- собрать проект средствами Maven из комадной строки, чтобы исключить проблемы с настройками IDE. Для этого в корне проекта выполните команду `mvn clean install`.

Вопрос по этой ошибке на английском: [Maven invalid LOC header (bad signature)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090921/maven-invalid-loc-header-bad-signature)

Comment: делал то, что вы описали. Спасибо! Это мне помогла сбежать от подобных ошибок. 
-Далее, выходят следующая сообщения.
 Failed to define class rts.data.databaseHelper in Module "deployment.OR.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link rts/data/databaseHelper (Module "deployment.OR.war:main" from Service Module Loader): rts/data/databaseHelper (wrong name: rts/data/DatabaseHelper)

Comment: @Ulukmyrza Это снова тема для отдельного вопроса. Вообще все ошибки `ClassNotFoundException`, `NoClassDefFound` означают, что указанный класс (`rts/data/databaseHelper`) не обнаружен. Чтобы решить проблему нужно найти где есть ссылки на класс, узнать где находится сам класс и проверить доступен ли он.  Так что если будете задавать вопрос по этой проблеме, опишите подробно что это за класс и как он попадает в сборку.